# Convert ArrayList to Desired Json format

Tags: javascript, c#, json

We have the result set which is returned as a List with parent, child, and some more columns. We want to convert that into the Json with parent converting to Id and Child to Corrresponding nodes. 
see example below

Returned result:

`parent | Child
 ab     | cd
 ab     | ef
 ab     | gh
 cd     | ij
 cd     | kl
 ef     | mn
 ef     | op
 gh     | qr
 ij     | st
 and so on`

expected Json:

`{
  "id": "ab",
  "label": "ab",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "cd",
      "label": "cd",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "ij",
          "label": "ij",
          "nodes": {
            "id": "st",
            "label": "st"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "kl",
          "label": "kl"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ef",
      "label": "ef",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "mn",
          "label": "mn"
        },
        {
          "id": "op",
          "label": "op"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "gh",
      "label": "gh",
      "nodes": {
        "id": "qr",
        "label": "qr"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Hope Question is clear, Please let me know either C# or js utility that helps me in doing this.

Thanks in Advance

## **Edited**

After some research,

```
public class TreeNode
{
public TreeNode()
{
    nodes = List<TreeNode>();   
}

String id {get; set;}
List<TreeNode> nodes {get; set;}
 }
```

**Method**

```
public List<TreeNode> FlatToHierarchy(List<TreeNode> list)
{
        var lookup = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();
        // actual nested collection to return
        List<TreeNode> nested = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode item in list)
        {
            if (lookup.ContainsKey(item.Parent))
            {
                lookup[item.Parent].Children.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                nested.Add(item);
            }
            lookup.Add(item.Part, item);
        }

        return nested;
 }
```

But this returns,

```
ab
|
--cd
  |
  --ij
--cd
 |
  --kl
ab
|
--ef
  |
  --mn
--ef
  |
   --op
```

and so on, which is not expected data.

**updated the question, so that it might be helpful for getting answers**.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to parse your JSON, maybe by using Newtonsoft.Json - that's all!

Comment: @duDE. Thanks, but i am new to C#, Finding difficulties in parsing and getting the expected Json.

Comment: Edited my question with research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we could write some code and it worked for us.

```
 public List<TreeNode> FillRecursive(List<T> eqpList)
    {

        List<TreeNode> list = new List<TreeNode>();
        //First Item in the list is our RootNode
        var FirstEqp = eqpList.FirstOrDefault();
        TreeNode RootNode = new TreeNode();
        RootNode.text = FirstEqp.Parent;
        RootNode.items.Add(new TreeNode() { text = FirstEqp.child });
        foreach (EquipmentHierarchySPList eqp in eqpList)
        {
            GetTreeStructureFromList(eqp, list, RootNode);
        }
        return list;

    }

    public void GetTreeStructureFromList(T eqp, List<TreeNode> list,TreeNode RootNode)
    {
        bool found = false;
        TreeNode FoundNode =  GetTreeNode((list.Count != 0 ? RootNode : null), eqp.Parent, out found);
        if (!FoundNode.IsNullValue())
            FoundNode.items.Add(new TreeNode() { text = eqp.child });
        else //this will execute only once.
            list.Add(RootNode);
    }

    public TreeNode GetTreeNode(TreeNode RootNode, string findText,out bool found)
    {
        //if RootNode is Null , just return;
        if (RootNode.IsNullValue())
        {
            found = false;
            return null;
        }

        if (RootNode.text.Equals(findText))
        {
            found = true;
            return RootNode;
        }
        for (int j = 0; ; j++)
        {
            if (j >= RootNode.items.Count)
            {
                found = false;
                return RootNode;
            }

            var final = GetTreeNode(RootNode.items[j], findText,out found);

            if (found == true)
                return final;

            if (final.IsNullValue())
                return RootNode;

        }

    }
}
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode()
    {
        items = new List<TreeNode>();
    }

    public string text { get; set; }

    public List<TreeNode> items { get; set; }

        public bool TreeCompare(string findText)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(text.CompareTo(findText));
        }



}
```

Thanks For Suggestions/Help.

Answer (score 1):

Please use JSON.Net or other json parsers.